# With HTMX, can I filter the html that's returned from the server?

Tags: htmx

For reasons, my server will often return html that's wrapped in a containing div:

```
<div class="useless-container">
   <!-- the actual juice -->
</div>
```

Is there a way to set up a filter in HTMX which I can use to modify the html, i.e. to reduce the containing div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Take a look at [hx-select](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-select/).

> The hx-select attribute allows you to select the content you want swapped from a response.

Comment: Promising! My issue with that is that it increases binding between the template and the usage-site, in that I'd have to know (and duplicate) the id(s) of the element(s) being returned. 

What I'd really want is kind of the inverse, i.e. select "useless-container" and then yield whatever it contains.

Comment: I see.. I don't think that's possible just by using htmx tags. You should use `htmx:beforeSwap` event to implement more generic swapping logic, where you can trim the reponse content depending on specific classes. Example of how you can overide the event: https://htmx.org/docs/#modifying_swapping_behavior_with_events

Comment: @user717847 `hx-select` doesn't need to deal with IDs. You can provide any CSS selector, so in your case you can write `hx-select=".useless-container > *"`, so it will take all the elements within `.useless-container`.

Comment: @AlexanderBurov ah that works great. Looking forward to being able to use ReSelect in 2.0.